# How to create a Python subprocess to do latent class analysis in R?

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I am trying to do a latent class analysis for survey data from another team. I am primary a Python user but one of the more appropriate tool is poLCA in R. So, I am trying to create a Python subprocess that create the script to run in R, create a result dataframe, and run the rest of the analysis in Python.

The problem I am running into now is that I have trouble creating a formula to be used in poLCA from all the columns in the dataframe, which can be close to a thousands.

In Python, I can do the following:

```py
formula = '+'.join(dataframe.columns.tolist)+'~1'
```

but in the poLCA syntax, I will be doing:
cbind(col1, col2, ..., coln)~1
without the quotation mark, which I am not sure how to creat such a thing in Python.

I think if I can create the formula using Python, then I will be able to complete the whole process in Python as well. 
Anyone know of a way as to how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

create the R syntax as a string in python - and then use as.formula() in R on the string.

Comment: This is not a solution for the given problem.